# Prepared query isn't working PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to use prepared queries, but this code isn't working, it just stucks on the first use of prepare(). Commenting the fist if() does nothing, now it stucks on the second. No connection problems/no errors, just stuck.

If I do all of this using just mysqli_query() everything works great.

```
function addUser($id){
/*
  if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = ?")){

    if (!($stmt->bind_param("s", $id))){
      return false;
    }

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      if ($stmt->num_rows!=0){
        return false;
      }

    }else{
      return false;
    }

  }else{
    return false;
  }*/

  if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users VALUES (?, '')")) {

    if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $id)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  return false;

}
```

and about debugging, if i change the code like this

```
function addUser($id){
  echo "1";
  if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = ?")){
    echo "2";
    if (!($stmt->bind_param("s", $id))){
      return false;
    } ...

  }else{
    echo "3";
  } ...
```

I'll see only "1" on the page.

start of the class:

```
class db{
    private $mysqli;

    function __construct($ip, $login, $password, $database){
      $this->mysqli = new mysqli($ip, $login, $password, $database) or die("Problem with DB connection!"); 
      $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    }
```

Comment: with single `=` you are assigning a value, with double you are comparing. Oops never mind, misread your code

Comment: I would suggest that you actually inspect and log out your errors. Currently you code does no error handling at all around your DB interactions.

Comment: @RST a single `=` is needed in this case.

Comment: @user3830889 what is `$this`?

Comment: I don't think there is much help that can be provided until you can talk about what basic debugging steps you have done to narrow this problem down.

Comment: @JayBlanchard this code is just a part of a class

Comment: The other thing to note is that, if the id field has a unique index, there is basically no reason whatsoever to do an extra select before hand.  Just go directly for the insert.  A unique index will disallow an extraneous insert anyway.

Comment: @MikeBrant as I said, it won't work with select and without it

Comment: @user3830889 That second comment was just an aside, not related to the problem.  The problem itself is vague as you have no information on debugging you have attempted.

Comment: @user3830889 You should add in appropriate `mysqli_error()` calls and turn on appropriate error loggin if not enabled to actually get information back on what is going wrong.  Without that, it is really impossible to help further.

Comment: Is commented part really important for question?

Comment: Based on you question edit around debugging, my guess is you are getting a fatal error on calling `prepare()` or getting a falsey value. You need to turn on error reporting. And not just return false if the if condition isn't met (call mysql_error and determine the problem).

Comment: the problem is that mysqli_error() and mysqli_errno() print nothing if I place them in the if or after it.

Answer (score 0):

You never `execute()` so nothing will happen, therefore no errors will raise.

Here is how I would write it:

```
function addUser($id){
    if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno);
    }
    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users VALUES (?, '')")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);//did you mean i  for type int ?
        $stmt->execute();//dont forget this!!
    }else{
        die('Connect Error: ' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno);
    }

    return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)? true : false;

}
```

Comment: i execute later in the function

Comment: well you cannot do this unless you return `$stmt` itself. which is pointless

Comment: @user3830889 why not execute it there?  if you want to execcute it later either return that object or use a property like you did you the connection